# How to have an inherited callback in ruby that is triggered after the child class is defined instead of before

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ruby: can I have something like Class#inherited that's triggered only after the class definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790626/ruby-can-i-have-something-like-classinherited-thats-triggered-only-after-the-c)

```
class A
  def self.inherited(child)
    puts "XXX"
  end
end

class B < A
  puts "YYY"
end
```

prints out

```
XXX
YYY
```

I'd prefer

```
YYY
XXX
```

if I could get it somehow.

Comment: Just answered the same question there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790626/ruby-can-i-have-something-like-classinherited-thats-triggered-only-after-the-c/7096259#7096259.

Comment: Just looked at that now. Looks very interesting. I'll check in detail in the morning. My specific use case is to force subglasses to implement a specific method. If the method is not there then the check will cause the class definition to fail early. My above example doesn't detail this but the define gem might give me the hooks I need. Thanks.

Comment: It's now possible to do this in Ruby using `TracePoint`. See my answer to the same question above. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790626/is-there-a-hook-similar-to-classinherited-thats-triggered-only-after-a-ruby-cl/34559282

Comment: Actually, my answer to another similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233860/how-can-i-set-a-hook-to-run-code-at-the-end-of-a-ruby-class-definition/34424483#34424483) is probably a better fit for your specific use case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can trace until you find the end of the class definition. I did it in a method which I called `after_inherited`:

```
class Class
  def after_inherited child = nil, &blk
    line_class = nil
    set_trace_func(lambda do |event, file, line, id, binding, classname|
      unless line_class
        # save the line of the inherited class entry
        line_class = line if event == 'class'
      else
        # check the end of inherited class
        if line == line_class && event == 'end'
          # if so, turn off the trace and call the block
          set_trace_func nil
          blk.call child
        end
      end
    end)
  end
end

# testing...

class A
  def self.inherited(child)
    after_inherited do
      puts "XXX"
    end
  end
end

class B < A
  puts "YYY"
  # .... code here can include class << self, etc.
end
```

Output:

```
YYY
XXX
```

Comment: This solution no longer works in modern versions of Ruby. Use `TracePoint`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790626/is-there-a-hook-similar-to-classinherited-thats-triggered-only-after-a-ruby-cl/34559282#34559282

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Consider this: when should a class definition be considered "done" in Ruby?

Instead of `self.inherited`, I would personally make a class method called `finalize!` and put your post-class-creation routine in there.

```
# A silly, contrived example

class A
  def self.author(person)
    @@authors ||= Array.new
    @@authors << person
  end

  def self.finalize!
    @@authors.map! { |a| Author[a] }
  end
end

class B < A
  author "Jason Harris"
  author "George Duncan"

  finalize!
end
```

You can probably get away with making a wrapper function instead:

```
class A
  def self.define_authors(&blk)
    yield
    # (...finalize here)
  end
  ...
end

class B < A
  define_authors {
    author "Jason Harris"
    author "George Duncan"
  }
end
```

...Or do consider that there may be ways where that finalizing step may not be needed.

Comment: See the comment above about the define gem. It looks like it might be possible.

Comment: This can now be done without installing any gems, by using `TracePoint`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790626/is-there-a-hook-similar-to-classinherited-thats-triggered-only-after-a-ruby-cl/34559282#34559282

Answer (score 0):

There is no such hook AFAIK.

A workaround could be:

```
class A
  @@my_lambda = nil
  def self.inherited(child)
    @@my_lambda = lambda { puts "XXX" }
  end

  def self.after_inherited
    @@my_lambda.yield
  end
end

class B < A
  puts "YYY"
  # other definitions
  self.superclass.after_inherited
end
```

It looks a bit messy but its output is:

```
YYY
XXX
```

This way you guarantee that your code in B gets executed before the after_interited() of A. So it does what you want but not the way you want to it.

Comment: The question is specifically asking how to trigger an after_inherited callback. Calling a callback explicitly from the child class is not really a callback at all.

Comment: You can't trigger a callback that does not exist however...

Comment: @mchl "it's not possible" is a valid answer. If you create that then I'll mark it as the correct one if nobody can come up with a clever hack to solve the problem. The above solution is just a round about way of writing "puts 'YYY'; puts 'XXX'" in the class body of B. Not really that instructive.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing: My solution is just a workaround. I thought you needed working code. Your question is misleading, you should have posted "Is there an inherited ...?"

Comment: No, it is not misleading. You've just concentrated your answer on matching the output with example, while it was.. well an example to show what comes after what.

Comment: Creating a hook is now possible using `TracePoint`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790626/is-there-a-hook-similar-to-classinherited-thats-triggered-only-after-a-ruby-cl/34559282#34559282