# How can I set a hook to run code at the end of a Ruby class definition?

Tags: ruby, plugins, loading

I'm building a plugin that will allow a developer to add various features to a class with a simple declaration in the class definition (following the normal acts_as pattern).

For example, code consuming the plugin might look like

```
class YourClass
  consumes_my_plugin option1: :value1, specific_method_to_use: :your_method
end
```

My question arises because I want to error check that the value provided for the :specific_method_to_use parameter exists as a method, but the way code is typically organized and loaded, the method doesn't exist yet.

The code in my plugin tentatively looks like this:

```
module MyPlugin
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def consumes_my_plugin(options = {})
      raise ArgumentError.new("#{options[:specific_method_to_use]} is not defined") if options[:specific_method_to_use].present? && !self.respond_to?(options[:specific_method_to_use])
    end
  end
end
```

This would work:

```
class YourClass
  def your_method; true; end

  consumes_my_plugin option1: :value1, specific_method_to_use: :your_method
end
```

But this is how most people write code, and it would not:

```
class YourClass
  consumes_my_plugin option1: :value1, specific_method_to_use: :your_method

  def your_method; true; end
end
```

How can I fail at YourClass load time? I want it to error then, not at run time with a NoMethodError. Can I defer execution of the line that raises the ArgumentError until the entire class is loaded, or do something else clever to achieve that?

Comment: Can you do the check at the point where you would have invoked `specific_method_to_use` instead of doing the check at class load time?

Comment: :specific_method_to_use only gets invoked at runtime, so although I could certainly catch the NoMethodError and provide constructive messaging to the developer around it, the bug would only be caught at runtime, not at load time...the latter being preferable I think.

Comment: The check you're doing using `self.respond_to?` won't check for the instance method `YourClass#your_method`; it will look for the singleton/class method `YourClass.your_method`. In my answer I modified it to `self.instance_methods.include?`. Feel free to change it back to `respond_to?` if I misunderstood your intention.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `TracePoint` to track when your class sends up an `:end` event.

---

**General solution**

This module will let you create a `self.finalize` callback in any class.

```
module Finalize
  def self.extended(obj)
    TracePoint.trace(:end) do |t|
      if obj == t.self
        obj.finalize
        t.disable
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can extend your class and define `self.finalize`, which will run as soon as the class definition ends:

```
class Foo
  puts "Top of class"

  extend Finalize

  def self.finalize
    puts "Finalizing #{self}"
  end

  puts "Bottom of class"
end

puts "Outside class"

# output:
#   Top of class
#   Bottom of class
#   Finalizing Foo
#   Outside class
```

---

**Specific solution to OP's problem**

Here's how you can fit `TracePoint` directly into your pre-existing module.

```
require 'active_support/all'

module MyPlugin
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def consumes_my_plugin(**options)
      m = options[:specific_method_to_use]

      TracePoint.trace(:end) do |t|
        break unless self == t.self

        raise ArgumentError.new("#{m} is not defined") unless instance_methods.include?(m)

        t.disable
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The examples below demonstrate that it works as specified:

```
# `def` before `consumes`: evaluates without errors
class MethodBeforePlugin
  include MyPlugin
  def your_method; end
  consumes_my_plugin option1: :value1, specific_method_to_use: :your_method
end

# `consumes` before `def`: evaluates without errors
class PluginBeforeMethod
  include MyPlugin
  consumes_my_plugin option1: :value1, specific_method_to_use: :your_method
  def your_method; end
end

# `consumes` with no `def`: throws ArgumentError at load time
class PluginWithoutMethod
  include MyPlugin
  consumes_my_plugin option1: :value1, specific_method_to_use: :your_method
end
```

Comment: This looks like exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you. My apologies that it did not award you the full bounty--I was traveling during the bounty-awarding period, and it won't seem to let me award the full amount.