# How to delay execution of extended method until after class is fully loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code:

```rb
module A
    def my_method
        puts self.instance_methods.include?(:my_base_method) 
    end
end

class B
    extend A

    my_method

    def my_base_method
    end
end
```

This prints false since the method is executed before the method `my_base_method` is defined. I can get this to return true by moving the execution until after `my_base_method` is defined

```rb
class B
    extend A

    def my_base_method
    end

    my_method
end
```

But in my code I ideally want `my_method` to be called at the top of the class for aesthetic purposes. Is there any way to accomplish this without having `my_method` called at the end of the class extending the module?

Comment: You can always call things after the fact, like `B.my_method`

Comment: @tadman, did you mean `B.extend A`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I mean you can wait for the class to be "settled" before calling methods on it by making method calls external to the class definition itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can leverage: [How can I set a hook to run code at the end of a Ruby class definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233860/how-can-i-set-a-hook-to-run-code-at-the-end-of-a-ruby-class-definition)

For example, you could leverage it like that:

```rb
module A
  def self.extended(obj)
    TracePoint.trace(:end) do |t|
      if obj == t.self
        validation_was_called = obj.instance_variable_defined?(:@_validation_ready)
        obj.instance_variable_set(:@_validation_ready, true)
        obj.validate_interface if validation_was_called
      end
    end
  end

  def validate_interface
    @_validation_ready ||= false
    puts "validation ready for #{name} ? #{@_validation_ready}"
    puts "Class #{name}: #{self.instance_methods.include?(:my_base_method) ? "OK" : "KO" }" if @_validation_ready
  end
end

class B
    extend A

    validate_interface

    def my_base_method
    end
end


class C
    extend A

    validate_interface
end
```

Output:

```
> validation ready for B ? false
> validation ready for B ? true
> Class B: OK
> validation ready for C ? false
> validation ready for C ? true
> Class C: KO
```

Comment: But at this point it's just easier to make the `validate_interface` a private method and to just call it at the end of the class evaluation (in the extended). So you can remove all of the @variable_instance logic.

Only issue with that is that it will be executed every single time a class extend a module. But then you could rather use a skip strategy. define a `skip_validation` class method, and perform the validation only if `skip_validation` has not been called for example.