# Some hook after initialization of ruby class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example I have some class with this initialization:

```
class SomeClass < ActiveRecord
  call_some_method('bla_bla_bla')
  def some_method
    return 1
  end
  # end of initialization or definition(not really sure, sorry)
  # and here I want to call some code which can be added in other place of project
end
```

And I want to add the hook with my own code which can add or call methods of class after initialization. I don't have ability to add some code into class definition directly and here I don't mean about initialization of class instances.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please use code that actually makes sense. It is impossible to inherit from `ActiveRecord`, as it is not a class. Did you mean `ActiveRecord::Base`? The only way to do this would be using tracing. Possible duplicate of [Is there a hook similar to Class#inherited that's triggered only after a Ruby class definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790626/is-there-a-hook-similar-to-classinherited-thats-triggered-only-after-a-ruby-cl/34559282#34559282)

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord has [after_initialize and after_find](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find) hooks, which you can use to run code after a record is initialized (via new or build) or loaded (via find).

You can use something like:

```
class SomeClass
  after_initialize :do_my_setup

  def do_my_setup
    # Your code here
  end
end
```

Which would monkeypatch SomeClass to run your setup method after a new record is instantiated. You could use this to patch in new methods to *instances* of ActiveRecord objects, but this will have some implications for the Ruby method cache, and is generally considered a bad idea if you can avoid it.

If you just need to add new methods to the `SomeClass` class - instance or class - you can just monkeypatch them in via the standard Ruby class extension mechanisms.