# In Ruby is it possible to define constants in a subclass from a superclass?

Tags: ruby, class, constants

Let's say I have a Ruby class that is extended by many subclasses. I want each of these subclasses to have a constant named `FRIENDLY_NAME`. Obviously, I can edit each of these classes and add the constant. But, if it's not specified in the subclass, is there a way to define a constant in a subclass from a superclass?

For example, maybe I could set each subclass' `FRIENDLY_NAME` to be the subclass' class name demodularized and underscored, when `FRIENDLY_NAME` is not already defined.

Comment: FWIW, I can use something like `child.const_set(:FRIENDLY_NAME, 'foo')` from `self.inherited` in the superclass, but that gives me a warning that I'm redefining a constant, even though I haven't yet defined it. "warning: already initialized constant"

Comment: Correction: The warning was coming from a class where I _did_ set the `FRIENDLY_NAME` constant. The problem is that `self.extended` in the super class is executed before the constant is defined in the subclass and there I'm setting the constant if it doesn't already exist. Thus, the warning is actually coming from the subclass when I'm trying to set its real value. :/

Comment: This is interesting, but not a good case for constants. You're effectively jumping through hoops to try and get this to behave how inheritance of methods already works, so I would use class level methods which are dead simple, understood by pretty much all Ruby devs, and which require no special knowledge of lesser known Ruby features like `TracePoint`: https://gist.github.com/meagar/0f8379ec706949594e76f9c91c7d6ec1

Comment: Honestly, you're right and a class method is exactly what I'll be doing. Still, like you said, it's interesting.

Answer (score 4):

TIL about `TracePoint`!

To expand on my original problem, I had a superclass I wanted to extend many times:

```rb
class BaseClass
end
```

I wanted all extended versions of the class to have a `FRIENDLY_NAME` constant. When specified explicitly in the subclass, that would be the value for the constant. EG:

```rb
class Subclass1 < BaseClass
  FRIENDLY_NAME = 'Bob seems like a friendly name!'
end
```

Thus:

```
pry(main)> Subclass1::FRIENDLY_NAME
=> "Bob seems like a friendly name!"
```

However, maybe I have another subclass where I don't define the constant. EG:

```rb
class Subclass2 < BaseClass
end
```

This is what I'd get without the constant (obviously):

```
pry(main)> Subclass2::FRIENDLY_NAME
NameError: uninitialized constant Subclass2::FRIENDLY_NAME
from /bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:79:in `block in load_missing_constant'
Caused by NameError: uninitialized constant Subclass2::FRIENDLY_NAME
from /bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:60:in `block in load_missing_constant'
```

How to add that constant? You can add `self.inherited` to the superclass. This method is called each time the superclass is extended. There's also a method on `Module` named `const_set`, so I could automatically set the constant on the child like this:

```rb
class BaseClass
  def self.inherited(child)
    child.const_set(:FRIENDLY_NAME, child.name)
  end
end
```

This works just fine for `Subclass2`:

```
pry(main)> Subclass2::FRIENDLY_NAME
=> "Subclass2"
```

However, it produces ugly warnings for `Subclass1`

```
(pry):10: warning: already initialized constant Subclass1::FRIENDLY_NAME
(pry):3: warning: previous definition of FRIENDLY_NAME was here
```

Initially I tried using the `const_defined?` method to check to see if the `FRIENDLY_NAME` constant was already defined. The problem is, the `self.inherited` method is invoked *before* the constant is defined in the subclass. Basically, as soon as Ruby see `< BaseClass` it runs `self.inherited`.

Eventually I found [this SO question about how to execute code after a class has been defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790626/is-there-a-hook-similar-to-classinherited-thats-triggered-only-after-a-ruby-cl). The answer there was to use `TracePoint`.

`TracePoint` is a class that allows us to handle events in our code. These could be when a line of code is executed, when we call a method, when an error is raised, etc. What we care about is `:end` event, which happens when a class or module definition is finished.

Knowing that, we can update our `self.inherited` method like this:

```rb
class BaseClass
  def self.inherited(child)
    TracePoint.trace(:end) do |t|
      if child == t.self
        unless child.const_defined?(:FRIENDLY_NAME)
          child.const_set(:FRIENDLY_NAME, child.code)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now, both `Subclass1` and `Subclass2` have a `FRIENDLY_NAME` constant, but neither produce warnings!